# Cocoapod installation : Error at line pod "Vanified ", :path => "../" in Podfile

Tags: ios, cocoapods

**This is my dependancies that i want to use in Podfile.**

```
platform :ios, '8.0'

use_frameworks!

target ‘Vanified', :exclusive => true do      
  pod "Vanified", :path => "../"
//Note "Vanified" is my Exaple_Framework
  pod 'Specta', '~> 0.2.1'    
  pod 'Expecta'    
end

target 'Tests', :exclusive => true do

end
```

**Note**: Before that i follow the steps which is given by https://cocoapods.org/

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here? `Vanified` is your private pod, I assume?

Answer (score 1):

`:path =>` refers to a local path to *another pod*.

That is, this doesn't make sense:

```
target ‘Vanified', :exclusive => true do

pod "Vanified", :path => "../"

end
```

This basically means "fetch `Vanified` as a local dependency of the `Vanified` pod."

You also don't need to refer to `Vanified` in the test target.

Instead, you should make the test target depend and link against your pod target (technically, static library or dynamic framework).

You can do this by going to the `Build Phases` for your test target and making sure (1) `Vanified` is in `Target Dependencies` and (2) `Vanified` is in `Link Binary with Libraries`.

Answer (score 1):

i assume Vanified is not you framework,i think you want to install another framework in your project & `Vanified` is your project name.

```
target ‘ Vanified', :exclusive => true do

pod "Example_Framework", :path => "../"

end
```

**That will help you.**

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion but its too late answer, i already did it.

Answer (score 0):

See if you are new to pod installation,i always do it following way

```
target 'TargetName' do   
  use_frameworks!
  # Pods for Yummy
  pod 'Your_Example_Frameworks1', '~> 1.0.0'
  pod ‘Your_Example_Frameworks2’

  target 'TargetName Tests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
  target 'TargetName UITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
end
```

**Hope this will help you**